# When I add AngularFireAuth to my constructor the site doesn't show up

Tags: angular, angularfire

The title says it all.

This is my code with Angular Fire Auth.

Nothing shows up.

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

[image: Nothing shows up]

And when i remove it

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

[image: It works]

it works

Comment: Did you check console for errors?

Answer (score 0):

> import firebase from "firebase/compat";

It was the error in this import. It should've been.

> import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).